# Ninject and Generic

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ninject

I'm trying to reuse NopCommerce code for data access using Ninject.
My Q: How can I inject unspecified generic type to an object?
I know NopCommerce uses Autofac.

My objects description: I have controller (`MyController`) which holds repository (`IRepository<T>`). This repository is injected as `EfRepository<T>` using ninject command: `kernel.Bind(typeof(IRepository<>)).To(typeof(EfRepository<>))`.
The `EfRepository` holds typeof `IDbContext`, which is generic `DbContext`.
`EfRepository` does not passes it's generic type to `IDbContext`, but still it is injected to it. How does it done using Ninject?

the code;

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    //a repository --> injected as EfRepository<> using generic injection using the command:
    //kernel.Bind(typeof(IRepository<>)).To(typeof(EfRepository<>));
    private readonly IRepository<Account> _repository;
}

public class EfRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : BaseEntity
{
    private IDbContext _context; //<<== How do I inject <T> to IDbcontext?
}

public interface IDbContext
{
    IDbSet<T> Set<T>() where T : BaseEntity;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because IDbContext isn't generic you can simple inject it to the repository and pass T to the generic Set method when you use it.

```
public class EfRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : BaseEntity
{
    private IDbContext context;
    public EfRepository(IDbContext dbContext)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void Do()
    {
        var dbSet = this.context.Set<T>();
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. This is very strait forward and simple.